# SceneKit broken in Xcode 6 beta 3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8, scenekit

Since updating to beta 3 anything that makes use of SceneKit throws 200 build errors when a device is targeted (works find in simulator). Even the sample SceneKit project fails to build now.

Is anyone else experiencing this issue and has anyone found a solution? I have tried deleting derived data, reinstalling, etc

```
<unknown>:0: error: /Applications/Xcode6-Beta3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SceneKit.framework/Headers/SceneKitTypes.h:8: could not build module 'simd'
<unknown>:0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'SceneKit'
```

Full build error log: http://pastebin.com/PQwCBLrg

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in Xcode beta 3 and SceneKit project don't compile on armv7(s) devices. However it works for arm64 devices (just be sure to enable "build active architecture only" in the Build settings so Xcode does not try to compile for armv7).

Answer (score 0):

This also only occurs when using Swift. Objective-C projects with SceneKit still compile fine for older devices.